# How can I map a single parameter to an uneven probability?

Tags: probability

Note: The title of this question is probably horrible, since I didn't know how to phrase this question correctly. So I am glad for any suggestions.

I am currently writing a game where a player gets assigned to one of three teams (A, B or C) randomly. However, I want this randomness to be controllable via a single parameter. There are three cases where I know how I would like my program to behave:

If the parameter is 1.0 (the maximum), then the player should always be assigned to team C.

If the parameter is 0.0 (the minimum), then the player should be assigned with probability 50:50 to either team A or B (and 0% to team C).

If the parameter is 0.5, then the player should be assigned to either a, b, or c with probability 1/3 (equal probability).

However, now I am stuck: The parameter should be selectable arbitrarily. So: How can I find out the equation that allows me to relate the parameter to the three probabilities? Or, rather, how can I calculate the probabilities, given the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an illustration of the many possibilities, if the parameter is $x$ then you could try

$$\Pr(A)=\Pr(B)=\frac{1-x^k}{2}$$
$$\Pr(C)=x^k$$

where $k=\dfrac{\log(3)}{\log(2)} \approx 1.5849625$.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much. This might sound really stupid, but how did you know what k would be?

Comment: Solving  $\left(\dfrac12\right)^k=\dfrac13$ by using logarithms

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the parameter that varies from $0$ to $1$.  Then $$Pr(a)=Pr(b)=-\frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}(-2x^2-x+3)$$
$$Pr(c)=\frac{2}{3}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x=\frac{1}{3}(2x^2+x)$$

This was obtained by taking quadratic interpolations of the three points specified (once for each formula).  That means that they satisfy exactly the conditions specified, for $x=0,0.5,1$.

Note that $$Pr(a)+Pr(b)+Pr(c)=\frac{1}{3}(-2x^2-x+3)+\frac{1}{3}(2x^2+x)=1$$

There are infinitely many ways to interpolate three data points; however this is the simplest possible solution as a polynomial.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering my question.

There are two things which are not quite clear to me here, though:

1) Is this an "exact" result or is an analytical result not possible in my case?

2) I see here that the two probabilities (Pr(a) + Pr(b) + Pr(c)) do not add up to 1. (e.g. for x = 0.9). Now I am a bit confused: Don't I have to somehow enforce that Pr(a)+Pr(b)+Pr(c) = 1 for it to be a "true" probability?

Comment: (1) I don't know what you mean by an "exact" result; this result meets all the conditions requested.  (2) You should check your calculations for $x=0.9$ again, I get 0.08, 0.08, 0.84 exactly.

Comment: Hi there! Sorry for 2), yes, I messed up my calculation.

What I meant by 1 is: You said that it was an interpolation, but these are (in general) not analytical, exact results, but just interpolations. So this was what I was wondering about.

The other answer used logarithms, which seems to imply a non-square result.

Comment: The other answer is an interpolation too.